# Django class based generic view “CreateView” form errors handling

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I am new to CBV and am trying to use the generic view `CreateView` and understand it.

In **models.py** I have this model:

```
class CartConfig(models.Model):

    cart_key = models.CharField(
       'Chave do Carrinho', max_length=40, db_index=True
    )
    PAYMENT_OPTION_CHOICES = (
        ('cash', 'Dinheiro'),
        ...
    )
    payment_option = models.CharField(
        'Opção de Pagamento', choices=PAYMENT_OPTION_CHOICES, max_length=20,
        default='cash'
    )
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, verbose_name='Endereço de entrega', 
        blank="false"
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Configuração do carrinho'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Configurações do carrinho'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Cart configs for {}'.format(self.cart_key)
```

That model uses a `ForeignKey` to `Address`, which is also a `ManyToMany`field in the `User` model.
So, in my **views.py** I edited the queryset of ´adress´ field to handle only the address relationed to the current `User`:

```
class CartConfigView(CreateView):
    model = CartConfig
    template_name = 'checkout/cart_config.html'
    fields = ['address','payment_option']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CartConfigView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'].fields['address'].queryset = get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.request.user.pk).address.all()
        context['form'].fields['address'].empty_label = None
        return context
```

In my template it works fine, show the right address list and creat it as well through the post form. But if the user don't select an address, it triggers the expected error `NOT NULL constraint failed: checkout_cartconfig.address_id`. The question is, should not the `CreateView` handles this error? What am I doing wrong? How can I do to the page refresh with the `field.errors` to show to the user the "required field" message?

Comment: blank should be a boolean `blank=False`. Perhaps the string "false" is resolving to truthy and not adding the `required` tag to the form input in the html.

Comment: @Brobin yeah, ashamed for this mistake hahah =(, thank u for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is not set up quite correctly with `blank="false"`. It needs to be a boolean.

```
address = models.ForeignKey(
    Address,
    verbose_name='Endereço de entrega',
    blank=False
)
```

Fun fact about Python: When resolving to a boolean, strings evaluate to true.

```
>>> bool("false")
True
```

Comment: Ow! Sorry for this ordinary mistake hahah. Thank u for the help, and nice fun fact =)